# GLSL + Scenekit: Function definition not allowed

Tags: c++, swift, opengl, glsl, scenekit

I'm trying to create a vertex shader in Scenekit. The shader is successfully added to the geometry of the SCNNode, however it displays purple because I get an error. I added the shaders to the geometry using SCNShaderModifiers and know that they are successfully found and attached.

The exact error messages I recieved is:

```
2020-08-31 21:26:53.977977-0700 Azure[69834:3664712] [SceneKit] Error: FATAL ERROR : failed compiling shader:
Error Domain=MTLLibraryErrorDomain Code=3 "Compilation failed: 

program_source:2901:97: error: function definition is not allowed here
float2 wavedx(float2 position, float2 direction, float speed, float frequency, float timeshift) {
                                                                                                ^
program_source:2908:49: error: function definition is not allowed here
float getwaves(float2 position, int iterations) {
                                                ^
" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Compilation failed: 

program_source:2901:97: error: function definition is not allowed here
float2 wavedx(float2 position, float2 direction, float speed, float frequency, float timeshift) {
                                                                                                ^
program_source:2908:49: error: function definition is not allowed here
float getwaves(float2 position, int iterations) {
                                                ^
}
```

However, when I am not using methods, the shader works perfectly. To test this I used a regular sinusoidal shader. The following example worked:

```
uniform float Amplitude = 0.1;
_geometry.position.z += sin(u_time + _geometry.position.x);
```

The code I was trying to get to work was this, which has functions:

```
float Time = u_time;
float DRAG_MULT = 0.048;

vec2 wavedx(vec2 position, vec2 direction, float speed, float frequency, float timeshift) {
    float x = dot(direction, position) * frequency + timeshift * speed;
    float wave = exp(sin(x) - 1.0);
    float dx = wave * cos(x);
    return vec2(wave, -dx);
}

float getwaves(vec2 position, int iterations) {
    
    float iter = 0.0;
    float phase = 6.0;
    float speed = 2.0;
    float weight = 1.0;
    float w = 0.0;
    float ws = 0.0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++){
        vec2 p = vec2(sin(iter), cos(iter));
        vec2 res = wavedx(position, p, speed, phase, Time);
        position += normalize(p) * res.y * weight * DRAG_MULT;
        w += res.x * weight;
        iter += 12.0;
        ws += weight;
        weight = mix(weight, 0.0, 0.2);
        phase *= 1.18;
        speed *= 1.07;
    }
    return w / ws;
}
```

I  have no idea what's going wrong here. These are all standalone GLSL snippets. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I added the shaders to the geometry using SCNShaderModifiers and know that they are successfully found and attached.

If you use `SCNShaderModifiers`, you also have to adhere to their [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadable):

> 2. Custom global functions. If your shader modifier benefits from factoring common code into functions, place their definitions here. If
>    you include custom functions in your snippet, you must place the
>    `#pragma body` directive between your function definitions and the main body of the snippet.

Comment: I was looking at their documentation, but it seeemed to combine OpenGL and Metal in one code snippet so I got very lost. Could you provide an example?

Comment: The page I linked _has_ a code example, and it also shows how you handle both Metal and OpenGL in it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, marking your answer as correct. The aprt that was causing problems for me was the extra snippet of metal code at the top, not sure why they put them both in one snippet.